# calculating average by rows sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of this type:

```
place                  time            id

 1. place 1 ----------------0-----------------------1
 2. place 1 ----------------141---------------------2
 3. place 1-----------------280---------------------3
 4. place 2-----------------0----------------------- 1
 5. place 2-----------------136---------------------2
 6. place 2-----------------260---------------------3
```

I would like to calculate an average of the time for each place for the resulting column to look something like this:

```
place                  time            id   avgTime

 1. place 1 ----------------0-----------------------1------140.333
 2. place 1 ----------------141---------------------2------140.333
 3. place 1-----------------280---------------------3------140.333
 4. place 2-----------------0-----------------------1------132
 5. place 2-----------------136---------------------2------132
 6. place 2-----------------260---------------------3------132
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a window function!

```
select t.*, avg(time * 1.0) over (partition by place) as place_avg
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query

```
SELECT id, place, time, (SELECT AVG(time) from places WHERE places.place = pls.place GROUP BY place) as avgTime FROM `places` as pls
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do your thing

```
SELECT *, AVG(1.0*time) OVER(PARTITION BY place) 
FROM yourTable
```

you can test it here

```
declare @table as  table (place varchar(100), time int, id int )

insert into @table (place, time, id)
values
('Place1', 0, 1),
('Place1', 141, 2),
('Place1', 280, 3),
('Place2', 0, 1),
('Place2', 136, 2),
('Place2', 260, 3)

select *, avg(1.0*time) over(partition by place) 
from @table
```

Answer (score -1):

TRY THIS

```
    select A.PLACE,
           A.TIME,
           A.ID,
          (select avg(TIME) from AVERAGE where PLACE =A.PLACE) avgTIME
    from AVERAGE A
    order by PLACE,ID
```